# Is the Safari in-app browser affected by ITP?

Tags: google-analytics, safari

In the Google Analytics account of a client I notice that safari in-app browser sessions have a much higher return rate than the Android webview browsers. The platform is an app - so one for IOS and one for Android. Which is a hybrid so it has some native elements and webview elements.

I've checked the cookie expiration of the _ga cookie and for both Android Webview and Safariin-app the expiration is set to 2 years. When I check safari browsers 12.1+ on the regular website (so not the app) then I notice that the _ga cookie expiration is set to 7 days - that's clearly ITP.

So it seems that the safari in-app browsers are not affected by ITP and that there is another reason for the loss of IOS _ga cookies. However, I can nowhere find if safari in-app browsers are really not affected by ITP?

Comment: Interesting observation. It seems that ITP doesn't affect pre-existing cookies (before the ITP update) but is only evaluated when creating a new cookie. In the context of an in-app browser, if the App has been installed for a while, they could remain and be older, than in the context of a web site where way more new visitors can come in and move away... ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So according to you new cookies set in the IOS app (Safari in-app) are affected by ITP and it’s not only applying to safari browsers 12.1+? 

I compared the android web view data (Android app) versus IOS app. So these platforms have the same context. Safari in-app reports a new user rate above 20% while the android web view is below 1% (it’s a personal banking app so lots of daily returning users). I also discovered that in April last year all IOS cookies have been resetted. So all the users got new cookies. Before the reset IOS new user rates were also below 1%.

Comment: it sounds like you confirm that it applies also to in-app usage ? What if you segment the share of new Users per version of iOS ?

Comment: The data is indeed pointing in that direction. However If I check the _ga cookie expiration in safari in-app then it’s being set to two years. If I check the cookie expiration for safari 12.1 + browser on the website (so the browsers of which I’m 100% sure that they are affected by ITP) then I see that the _ga cookie expiration is set to 7 days. So if safari in-app would be affected by ITP then I would expect so see the same cookie duration as for 12.1 +browsers. Furthermore I see that the share of returning users that return within 2 days are much higher for Android Webview. In case of ITP...

Comment: I would expect to see a big difference in returning users after 7 days. So that’s why I’m doubting if ITP affects safari in-app users. I’ll check the OS versions next week, but what information can this give me? Are the os versions related to the safari versions?

Comment: Yes, Safari updates are pushed by iOS and OSX updates, and so are ITP changes: they come i through OS updates. See https://clearcode.cc/blog/intelligent-tracking-prevention/

Comment: Thanks for that link. I've checked the OS versions and for Safari in-app all OS versions show similar new session rates. 

If I look at new session rates by OS version for regular safari browsers (on the website, not the app) then I clearly see that the older OS versions have lower new session rates. 

This confirms my assumption that the change in new session rates (red: cookie reset / expiration) for sarfari in-app is in this case probably caused by something else then ITP. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm wondering in fact if Apps inherit the webkit engine version that is used when being compiled ? Then it would depend on how often and when apps are updated ? Safari release dates are there https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201222 
you'll see it syncs with OS updates

Comment: I've consulted an Apple developer and he confirms that ITP does not affect WKWebViews, only Safari 12.1+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've consulted with an Apple developer and he confirms that ITP does not affect WKWebViews, only Safari 12.1+.

Answer (score 2):

Apple is turning on ITP by default in WKWebView for iOS and iPadOS starting in September of 2020 with iOS14 and iPadOS14.  This means it will affect the Safari browser as well as all other iOS and iPadOS browsers (since they are required to be built on WKWebView).  It seems likely that this will affect in-app browsers as well.

[SimaHava's breakdown of the new changes](https://www.simoahava.com/privacy/intelligent-tracking-prevention-ios-14-ipados-14-safari-14/)

[John Wilander's (Apple engineer behind ITP) post about this](https://twitter.com/johnwilander/status/1276205640604545025)